# Filtering any data type stored in varbinary in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using `SQL Server 2008` and I want to store any data type (int, float, date & time, string, files, etc) in one table:

```
create table T
(
  [type] int,
  [value] varbinary(max)
)
```

Column `[type]` helps me to interpret data stored in column `[value]` in my `C#` application.

How can I get all rows with value higher than `0.7` using query `select * from T where [type] = N and ...` (`N` guarantees that `[value]` stores `float`)? Can I do it if I first convert `0.7` to binary in my `C#` application and than send it to `SQL Server`?

Or how cat I get all strings containing `%cat%`? Is `Full-Text Search` engine helpful in this situation?

I do not want to `cast` values, because I need lots of `if` statements then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around the problem I have understood that there is no solution. You cannot make `SQL Server` compare two `float` values presented as `varbinary`, for example, without casting to float.

As it is impossible to filter data stored in one `varbinary` column I have created four more columns that contain `SQL Server` base data types (`int`, `float`, `datetime`, `nvarchar`). Each user data type is now mapped to `SQL Server` base type.

Now I can filter any user type (except `varbinary`, but I do not need to filter images or files) and each row uses only one column related to that type (others have `NULL` values).